# take first element of css

Tags: jquery, element

Hello i have two css style for one element the first within attribute style and the second within the jquery attribute css  and i want take the first
like that:

---

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {

 jQuery(".iview-group-19").iView({
  captionSpeed: 500, // speed to show caption
  captionOpacity: 1, // caption opacity
  captionEasing: 'easeInOutSine', // caption transition easing effect, use JQuery Easings effect
  customWidth: 1920,
  customHtmlBullet: false,
  rtl: false,
  height:500,

    }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iview iview-group-19" id="slide-height" style="height: 351px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if style element is exist or not in element. If not exist in inline attribute. JQuery css style will render. Element inline always take first priority. In case style attribute missed in element, jquery css replace that style.

```js
$(function(){

if(!$("h1").attr("style")){
  $("h1").css({
     "margin":"7px",
     "border":"10px solid red !important",
     "padding":"10px" 
  });
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="margin:1px;border:1px solid red;padding:10px;" >
Hello test
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
 style="height: 351px !important;"
```